# code not retrieving data from json

Tags: android

Where have I gone wrong in this code? The data doesn't show after the button is pressed. I have referenced this from [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/volley-json-parsing).

Am I leaving out any code that causes it to not work? It would be a great help to point me to where I have gone wrong and explain it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();
            }
        });
    }

    private void jsonParse() {

        String url = "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/soccer/json/champions-league-20172018-standings.json";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String GroupName = data.getString("name");
                                int position = data.getInt("position");
                                String TeamName = data.getString("team_name");

                                mTextViewResult.append(GroupName + ", " + String.valueOf(position) + ", " + TeamName + "\n\n");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: int position = data.getInt("position"); there is no position in the data object.

Comment: what do you mean by that? as in the JSON URL? if you are referring to that, there is.

Comment: The response that we are receiving does not contain the position object.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the JSON response with this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String groupName = data.getString("name");

                JSONObject standingsObject = data.getJSONObject("standings");
                JSONArray standingsDataArray = standingsObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int j = 0; j < standingsDataArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject dataGroup = standingsDataArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    int position = dataGroup.getInt("position");
                    String teamName = dataGroup.getString("team_name");

                    mTextViewResult.append(groupName + ", " + String.valueOf(position) + ", " + teamName + "\n\n");
                }
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: still doesnt work. i assumed im suppose to replace the onResponse method

Comment: After a small tweak the edited code above works...I have tried it! I originally made a copy/paste error inside the second `for` loop-- I should have had `standingsDataArray` instead of `jsonArray`. Also note that you need to get `groupName` from inside the first loop.